# auto as function argument

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, auto

In C++14 something like this was made legal (for `lambdas`) :-

```
auto l = [](auto x, auto y) { return x+y; };
```

However something like this is still not legal :-

```
auto sum (auto x, auto y)
{
     return x+y;
}
```

My curiosity is why wasn't the second one added to the standard (though it is supposed to be added in C++17 hopefully) ? What were the pros & cons of the second one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It wasn't added because it's another thing to add and time is not infinite. We cannot expect all useful enhancements to be added in one go, can we? As you have identified, it will be in C++17.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Time is infinite or time is finite or time is both? Paging [physics.stackexchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: To make everyone happy, we'll say time is `O(infinity)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of a TS that wasn't ready in time for C++14.

It is going to be equivalent to

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto sum(T x, U y) { return x+y }
```

The only pro is that it's slightly shorter. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Including the ODR ramifications? Definition in each TU etc? (Must be, I suppose - which makes me think this new feature is just a big heap of confusion waiting to happen)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i don't think it will be confusing if one is used to templates

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: Perhaps but the feature is literally "make a template look like a non-template". Doesn't seem like a brilliant idea to me.